# Button is not clickable by Selenuim (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a script that uses Selenium (Python).

I tried to make the code click a button that it acknowledges is clickable, but throws an error stating it;s not clickable.

Same thing happens again in a dropdown menu, but this time I'm not clicking, but selecting an option by value.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import *
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Getting to Chrome and website
website = 'https://www.padron.gob.ar/publica/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(website)
driver.maximize_window()

#"BUENOS AIRES" in "Distrito Electoral"
distritoElectoralOptions = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'site')
Select(distritoElectoralOptions).select_by_value('02   ')

#Clicking "Consulta por Zona
WebDriverWait(driver, 35).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'lired')))
consultaPorZona = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'lired')
consultaPorZona.click()

#"SEC_8" in "Sección General Electoral"
WebDriverWait(driver, 35).until(EC.visibility_of((By.NAME, 'secg')))
seccionGeneralElectoral = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'secg')
Select(seccionGeneralElectoral).select_by_value('00008')
```

I'm getting this error on line 21:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: element has zero size

It works in a ipython notebook if each section is separated, but only if the option "Run all" is not used. Instead, the kernel has to be run on it's own.
I'm using VS Code.

Also, when it reaches the last line, when run in ipynb format, it throws this error:

> Message: Cannot locate option with value: 00008

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try using javascript to click on the element

Answer (score 0):

When a web element is present in the `HTML-DOM` but it is not in the state that can be interacted. Other words, when the element is found but we can’t interact with it, it throws `ElementNotInteractableException`.

The `element not interactable` exception may occur due to various reasons.

- Element is not visible
- Element is present off-screen (After scrolling down it will display)
- Element is present behind any other element
- Element is disabled

**If the element is not visible then wait until element is visible. For this we will use wait command in selenium**

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someid')))
element.click()
```

**If the element is off-screen then we need to scroll down the browser and interact with the element.**
Use the `execute_script()` interface that helps to execute JavaScript methods through Selenium Webdriver.

```py
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://en.wikipedia.org")
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,1000)") //scroll 1000 pixel vertical
```

Reference this solution in to the regarding problem.